# Pivot_wider introduces NA's

Tags: r, dplyr

I am doing datamanagement for a project and I am running into difficulties with what I thought would be a basic reshape from Long format to Wide.

The Data looks something like this:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
               Time = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
               Type = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B","C", "D", "A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B"),
               Value = c(100, NA, 40, 123, 95, NA, 45, 1234, 100, 70, NA, 50, 12345, 75, NA)), 
               row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Based on previous Stackoverflow Answers I am trying to use pivot-wider like this:

```
df.wide <- df %>%
  group_by(ID, Type) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Type, values_from = Value)
```

However this returns a dataframe with NA values at max(Time) for each ID that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 7
     ID  Time   row     A     B     C     D
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1   100    NA    40   123
2     1     2     2    95    NA    45  1234
3     1     3     3   100    NA    NA    NA
4     2     1     1    70    NA    50 12345
5     2     2     2    75    NA    NA    NA
```

What am I doing wrong? My google and Stackoverflow-fu has not been able to help me.

Comment: Add `values_fill = list(Value = 0)` to replace NA's with 0 in your pivot_wider call.

Comment: ... pivot_wider simply fills up the wide dataset with NAs for combinations which are not present in your long dataset.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just realized the NA's at the final timepoint were an unintended consequence of the test dataset I constructed.I feel so stupid but thank you both for the helpful answers anyway!

Comment: I just used values_fill = 0 instead when I needed to do this - seems to work - am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

The `pivot_wider()`-ed data has two kinds of NAs:

1. the NAs already in the dataset, and
2. those introduced by pivoting the data wider, in places where there is no value present in the data for a given row and column.

To get rid of type 1, you can use `df |> replace_na(list(Value = 0))`.
To get rid of type 2, you can use the argument `values_fill = 0` (or if you only want to remove them from a particular column, then you can name the column, e.g. `values_fill = list(Value = 0)`)

To remove them both, you can do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  replace_na(list(Value = 0)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = Type, values_from = Value, values_fill = 0)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 6
     ID  Time     A     B     C     D
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1   100     0    40   123
2     1     2    95     0    45  1234
3     1     3   100     0     0     0
4     2     1    70     0    50 12345
5     2     2    75     0     0     0
```

Alternatively, you could pivot the data wider without values_fill, then use `replace_na(list(A = 0, B = 0, C = 0, D = 0))`, but the option above is more concise.